# iPhone FaceBook Connect returns NULL email if not shared

Tags: iphone, facebook

I have integrated facebook connect into my Xcode 4 project for an iPhone. Here is the code for iPhone FBconnec. FBconnect.h and FBSession.h already included.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{ _session = [[FBSession sessionForApplication:@"APPKey" 
                                      secret:@"APPSecret" 
                                    delegate:self]retain];

FBLoginButton* fbButton = [[[FBLoginButton alloc] init] autorelease];
fbButton.frame = CGRectMake(228, 50, 85, 50);
[self.view addSubview:fbButton]; }
```

The code is working fine, but for some facebook accounts when run the FQL query to select email from user. I get NULL as shown below

```
length of users Array: (
    {
    "contact_email" = "<null>";
    email = "<null>";
    "first_name" = Ali;
    "last_name" = Subhani;
    uid = 696377693;
}
```

How can I get the extended permission. I am just using following code to run the query. Which contains word params, I think it has to do something with FBRequest. Have a look at the code below

```
- (void)getFacebookName {

//==================== MAKING FACEBOOK REQUEST =============================
NSString* fql = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                 @"select uid,first_name,last_name,email from user where uid == %lld",
                 self._session.uid];
NSDictionary* params =
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fql
                            forKey:@"query"];

[[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self]
 call:@"facebook.fql.query" params:params];}
```

Where should I enter extended permissions so I can get user email.

Comment: Are you sure those users have an email address in their profile? Are their privacy settings allowing you to see it? Sometimes, data is null but valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use

```
[appDelegate.facebook authorize:
  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    @"offline_access", @"email", @"user_checkins", @"publish_checkins", nil]
                       delegate:delegate 
                     localAppId:localAppId];
```

...to authorize and request email access (using the `@"email"` permissions key above). I'm not sure if a user can have NO email address, as they have at least one to login with.

However, Facebook gives the user the option to obfuscate it from you with an arbitrary @facebook.com account that forwards to their regular email account.

Comment: Is appDelegate.facebook is your FBSession?

Comment: It's the global Facebook object (from Facebook.h).

Comment: Can you please paste the link of libraries, the one i am using for iphone project does not contain Facebook.h